# Cambiar ruta para guardar una imagen de la camara

Tags: java, android, local-storage

Tengo un programa que, tras realizar una foto, la guarda en la memoria interna. El caso es que me la guarda en la carpeta raiz del proyecto (Android/data/..../files), pero quiero que me la guarde en una carpeta específica y no sé qué parámetro tengo que cambiar para ello.

Aquí el código de la creación del archivo a partir de la foto:

```
    //-------------METODO TOMAR FOTO CON LA CAMARA-------------
    public void captureImage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File imageFile = null;
            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(imageFile!=null){
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------METODO CREAR ARCHIVO-------------
    private File getImageFile() throws IOException{
        String imageName = "photo";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }
```

El contenido del archivo con el path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Y la parte del AndroidManifest con el provider:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ese cabmbio pequeño.

```
private File getImageFile() throws IOException{
        String imageName = "photo";
        String ruta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File storageDir = new File(ruta + "/miimagenes");

        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }
```

Y por supuesto no olvides añadir permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho pero la ejecución se para en la línea del File imageFile, y no me deja usar la cámara si cambio eso (habiendo dado los permisos anteriormente claro)

Comment: Y te sale algun error ?

Comment: Vale es una tontería. El error era que no tenía creada la carpeta en la que se almacenarían las fotos. ¡Gracias por tu ayuda! Aunque tengo una última duda. Ya que necesito que la app cree esa carpeta, ¿cómo hago para que compruebe que existe?

Comment: Prueba con esto if (storageDir.isDirectory())

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Si la respuesta de @TomaszVizaint te ha servido de ayuda, marcala con ✔ para ayudar a la comunidad que tenga la misma pregunta a encontrar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente es muy importante cambiar el archivo `provider_paths.xml`, este debe definir directorios en los cuales se guardarían los archivos, no debes definir "." o "/" ya que esto implica una vulnerabilidad. Define los directorios por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="archivos/" />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="archivos/" />
</paths>
```

Esto debes corregirlo antes del día 08/31/2020 para poder subir tu aplicación Google Play, esta es la información:

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7496913?hl=en

> Las implementaciones de openFile y openAssetFile en ContentProviders
> exportados pueden ser vulnerables si no validan adecuadamente los
> parámetros Uri entrantes. Una aplicación maliciosa puede proporcionar
> un Uri diseñado (por ejemplo, uno que contenga "/../") para engañar a
> su aplicación para que devuelva un ParcelFileDescriptor para un
> archivo fuera del directorio deseado, permitiendo así que la
> aplicación maliciosa acceda a cualquier archivo accesible para tu
> aplicación

Con respecto a lo que deseas realizar

> El caso es que me la guarda en la carpeta raiz del proyecto
> (Android/data/..../files) pero quiero que me la guarde en una carpeta específica y no sé qué parámetro tengo que cambiar para ello.

Actualmente para evitar vulnerabilidades en tu aplicación si usas un `ContentProvider`, los archivos de cada aplicación deberán guardarse dentro del directorio especificado por el paquete de la aplicación y dentro del directorio `/files` que seria :

```
Android/data/<package name>/files
```

Si deseas cambiar a otro directorio sería dentro de la estructura que crea la app, por ejemplo:

```
 <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="archivos/" />
```

.

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider/archivos"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

se guardaria en :

```
Android/data/<package name>/files/archivos
```